# How do i print the longest and shortest words out of a given set of words?

Tags: python, list

What I want is to write a code to detect the longest and shortest words from those given in a list. I tried to write a code to find the longest word using the number of characters which failed really bad...I'm wondering if there is a simple function or line that I'm missing.

```
mywords=['how','no','because','sheep','mahogany']

n = len(mywords)

a=0
while a < n:

print(( len( list(mywords[a]))))
a += 1

if a > n:
    break
```

though i do get a print of the number of characters of each word i cant figure out how to proceed.

PS : id like to know how to create a list from the values obtained as the result from the above function

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `max`, and `min`.

```
>>> max(mywords, key=len)
'mahogany'
>>> min(mywords, key=len)
'no'
```

Comment: Great! This worked! Could you tell me what "key" means in here? and thanks ^_^

Comment: `key` is what is used to compare the elements. In this case it will compare the elements based on their length.

Answer (score 4):

Just for diversity, here is another way to do it-

```
#Finding Max-value
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x if(len(x) > len(y))else y, mywords)
'mahogany'
#Finding Min-value
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x if(len(x) < len(y))else y, mywords)
'no'
```

Comment: There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik Yep max-min is the obvious way... but this is for diversty and using anon-func is fun... :P

Comment: reduce function is now in functools module (starting from py3k)

Answer (score 1):

At the expense of readability, you can obtain both at once by grabbing the first and last elements of a version of the list sorted by word length:

```
mywords=['how','no','because','sheep','mahogany']

shortest, longest = (w[i] for i in (0, -1) for w in (sorted(mywords, key=len),))
print shortest, longest  # no mahogany
```